# Restricting access to a single app and preventing access to wifi settings

Tags: multiple-devices, kiosk-mode, restricted-profiles, wifi-password

I'm looking to configure some Android tablets for shared use in a work environment so they can be used as mobile terminals for an ERP system. In case it matters the test device right now is the Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2019 running Android 9 but I'm open to deploying other devices if there's options that work on other models.

The tablets will need to connect to our restricted wifi network which is authenticated individually normally (we don't have shared devices currently) so I was thinking of connecting to the network with a shared/generic user on the admin account and then trying to restrict access to the wifi settings so that shared users of the device can't access the password.

Unfortunately after creating a restricted user I couldn't see a way to restrict access to the wifi settings which has an option to present a QR code for others to be able to access the same wifi network with those same credentials and configuration.

If I use the guest user they don't seem to have any way to open the application that we need and also once they log out all their session data is thrown away which would require a painful setup process on the business application we need to use each time and require a privileged user to intervene.

I also explored pinning the application which does prevent users from directly accessing the wifi settings (and is probably what we'd want anyway as these would only be used for this application) but anyone with knowledge of the unlock credentials (eg swipe pattern/pin/password) for the user would still be able to unpin and access the wifi settings. Because these devices are being deployed across multiple sites this would cause issues as we'd need to expand the group of trusted people with knowledge of these credentials and thus access to the wifi password that would need rotating when any of those people left.

Ideally, I'd like a way to be able to just use restricted profiles without access to the wifi settings/being able to read the wifi password because then we can leave that restricted profile as just swipe to unlock and there's nothing else sensitive on the device. Is there a way to do this? Am I missing a better option for shared Android devices?

Comment: Applying restrictions on corporate Android devices is usually done using an MDM system. There are dozens of MDM systems available - you can check what restrictions those MDM systems support.

Comment: I'm equally open to suggestions around applying MDM systems if the answer can show a minimally useful how to get started with them or point to other useful resources that will achieve the same goals.

Comment: Try some of the kiosk applications from Play Store. Some of them  not only has the feature of limiting the apps a user can access (see actually) but also limit access to Settings including quick settings, status bar and notification bar. Try them!

Comment: @Firelord thanks. That sounds like it could be fleshed out into a proper answer if you have time to do that? Particularly if you can recommend a specific one and show how to configure it etc.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR sorry, if I could find time I would have recommended one for sure.